# How to search for multiple words on a HTML page using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

Right now my code is looking for the words 'Cheese' or 'Bread' within a specific webpage, and if it finds either word it should display an alert. However, it only displays the alert if the first word is found (cheese). Any suggestions on how to fix it so that it will successfully look for more than one word?

```
var array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'))
    .find(el => el.innerText.includes('Cheese', 'Bread'));
    if (array){
      alert("Word found!")
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an obvious change, but we could put an OR operator inside of the statement to signify both of them, like so:

```
let array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'))
    .find(el => el.innerText.includes('Cheese') || el.innerText.includes('Bread'));
if (array) alert('Word found!');
```

You could also do it a more elegant way, like so:

```
const conditions = ['Cheese', 'Bread'];

const array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'));

const results = array.find((el) => conditions.some(nEl => el.innerText.includes(nEl)));

if (results) alert('Word found!');
```

This one works by grabbing the array from the 'wide-content-host' class name, then looping through that array with another loop that is looping through the values of the conditions array. With all of these loops working together, it will check whether or not the elements include the conditions.

** Edit **

In order to make the methods work without case-sensitivity, you would need to make the search cases lowercase e.g. 'cheese' and 'bread', and you would need to make the strings that you are searching through completely lowercase also.

Here are the examples for case-insensitivity:

```
let array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'))
    .find(el => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes('Cheese') || el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes('Bread'));
if (array) alert('Word found!');
```

or

```
const conditions = ['cheese', 'bread'];

const array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'));

const results = array.find((el) => conditions.some(nEl => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(nEl)));

if (results) alert('Word found!');
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you! Just wondering, could I adjust it to be not be case sensitive? So with 'Cheese' in my conditions, it would find 'Cheese' within text whether it was written 'Cheese', 'cheese',  'ChEeSe' etc.

Comment: Glad to hear it works perfectly! In order for case-insensitive-y, you would need to search for lowercase conditions, e.g. 'cheese' and 'bread', and you would make everything in the array lowercase.

Here's an example

```
let array = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('wide-content-host'))
    .find(el => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes('cheese') || el.innerText.includes('bread'));
```

or

```
const conditions = ['cheese', 'bread'];

const array = ...

const results = array.find((el) => conditions.some(nEl => el.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(nEl)));
```

Comment: That comment I made looks really horrible, I will edit the answer also.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with regular expressions

```js
let elem = document.querySelector("section");
let entries = elem.innerHTML.match(/(cheese)|(bread)/gi);

if (entries.length > 0) {
  alert(`Words were found: ${entries}`);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <p>Cheese Bread</p>
  <p>cheeSE BREAD</p>
</section>
```